# insert 2d arrays into one 3d array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to insert some 2d array to a 3d one..
the code is running well but I have difficulties with the insert command.
all of the 2d arrays are correct but when I insert them the 3d array int updating (only zeros)

```
def binarySeqs (seq_list):
    """taking dna sequences and returning a 3d matrix """
    lenght=len(seq_list[0])
    num_of_seq=len(seq_list)
    for i in seq_list:
        if lenght!=len(i):
            raise ValueError ("Invalid list of sequences")
    for i in seq_list:
        if set(i).issubset("ACGT")==False :
            raise ValueError ("Invalid list of sequences")
    basedict={'A':0 , 'T':1 ,'C':2 , 'G':3}
    my_array=np.zeros(( num_of_seq, 4, lenght))
    #print(my_array.shape)
    for l in seq_list:
        dmat=seqBinary(l)
        #print(dmat)
        for i in range((num_of_seq)):
            #print(i)
            np.insert(my_array ,i , dmat, axis=0 )           
    return my_array
```

Answer (score 0):

[numpy.insert](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) is not in-place operation, it does return changed array, consider following example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.insert(a, 1, [5])
print(a)  # [1 2 3]
print(b)  # [1 5 2 3]
```

So you should assign changed array back to variable, i.e. instead of

```
np.insert(my_array ,i , dmat, axis=0 )
```

do

```
my_array = np.insert(my_array ,i , dmat, axis=0 )
```